# Why no electric lines of force exist inside the charged body?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

[image]

My question is that why electric field lines can't pass through charged body...... And if they pass through a charged body then what will happen??

Answer (score 2):

> why electric field lines can't pass through charged body

They can, in general.

The description given here applies for a conductor in an electrostatic condition, but not for other types of charged bodies. For example, a charged insulator or electret, or even a non-electrostatic conductor.

For the special case of a conductor in electrostatic equilibrium we have the following two conditions.

From being a conductor we have $\vec J=\sigma \vec E$ where $\sigma$ is the conductivity, $\vec J$ is the current density, and $\vec E$ is the E field.

From electrostatic equilibrium we have $\vec J=0$.

Then by substitution $$0=\sigma \vec E$$$$\vec E=0$$

So there can be no field lines inside a conductor in an electrostatic situation.

Comment: So why electric field lines can't pass through for a conductor in electrostatic condition?

Comment: @Physicsstudent I updated the answer to include that

Comment: And I have a question that how can a conductor carry charge??

Comment: That is a different question. Please post it as a new question. In the question be detailed and clear about why you would think that a conductor cannot carry charge. The reason for that assumption is not immediately clear

Comment: Plz answer my new question dale..... I have a doubt with your statement.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that charges inside conductor cannot flow in electrostatic conduction. But charges do accumulate on the surface of conductor creating a dipole which compensates the external electric field inside the conductor. This leads to zero electric field inside the conductor. This is valid if conductor is not connected to a battery, which allows the charges to flow, leading to a net electric field inside the conductor.